# How can I check a file is closed or not in python?

Tags: python, file

How can I check the file "file_name" is still open or not with this command?

```
csv_gen = (row for row in open(file_name))
```

I know we should use something like

```
with open(file_name) as file_name_ref:
    csv_gen = (row for row in file_name_ref)
```

but what's happened and how can I check the behavior if I use the former command.

Comment: The second one is not correct either if you don't consume the generator before the end of the `with` statement.

Comment: You can assume the file will be closed when you're outside the context manager

Comment: @wjandrea  There's no reference to the object  in the first case with which you can check the `closed` attribute.

Comment: @chepner Oh, I get it now, they want to check if it's still open *after* the snippet

Comment: Yeah; it *should* stay open until the `generator` object is garbage-collected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a list of all open files using platform-independent module `psutil`:

```
import psutil
open_files = [x.path for x in psutil.Process().open_files()]
```

If `file_name` is on the list, then it is open, possibly more than once.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to dig into the `generator` object itself to find the reference to the `TextIOWrapper` instance returned by `open`; that instance has a `closed` attribute.

```
csv_gen.gi_frame.f_locals['.0'].closed
```

Once the generator is exhausted, `gi_frame` will become `None`, at which point whether the file is closed or not depends on whether the `TextIOWrapper` has been garbage-collected yet.

(This is a terrible way to do this, but I spent 10 minutes digging into the object, so wanted to share :) )